# Can i reduce ghci's memory usage?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I installed GHC-7.4 on an old freebsd box with 512M RAM.  All works great ! But the GHCI occupies too much RAM once started.

Any suggestion is appreciated !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `ghci +RTS -M100M -c30`, if you want to limit heap size to 100MB and using compaction when heap usage increases to 30%.

See [RTS](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html) options for more information on runtime flags.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, use the compiler rather than the interpreter.